# How can I use the DISQUS count link in my asp.net mvc 4 razor link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, comments, disqus

I have a razor link that looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId })
```

In the Disqus install info it says:

> Place the following code before your site's closing  tag:

```
<javascript>
```

I have done that.

Then it says step 2:

Append `#disqus_thread` to the href attribute in your links. This will tell Disqus which links to look up and return the comment count.

For example: `<a href="http://foo.com/bar.html#disqus_thread">Link</a>`

**Question**

How can I add  `#disqus_thread` when i'm using a htmlhelper extension?

**What I've tried**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId + "#disqus_thread" })
```

but that generates:

```
<a href="/Home/Comment/4656%23disqus_thread">Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need escape character like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId + "**&#35;**disqus_thread" })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I found to do it:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "ViewPost", "Posts", new { id = item.Id, slug = item.URL + "#disqus_thread" }, null).ToString()))
```